# Getting cursor position outside JS event?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mouse-cursor, mouse-position

I want to get cursor position relative to the window, but not inside the JS event. Something like `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` but not for event, for the window itself.

Comment: `but not inside the JS event.` what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @lusc Yes, exactly. Thanks a lot. Didn't found that question before